# Order of products to form System Matrix

Tags: matrices

Can anyone help explain why does the System Matrix start from the Last process to the first process?

Example:

- Process 1: T1
- Process 2: S1
- Process 3: T2
- Process 4: S2
- Process 5: T3

System matrix = product of all process = T3.S2.T2.S1.T1

Presentation slide [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTbnN.jpg)